# SQL Grant SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

I want to create a user and only allow them to use select statements on the `cameracircle` database. So I have the following code:

```
CREATE USER 'hoeym'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
CREATE DATABASE cameracircle;
GRANT SELECT ON cameracircle TO 'hoeym'@'localhost';
```

But the phpmyadmin doesn't like that. If I run this it says there is an error cause I don't have a databases selected, and if I add in `USE cameracircle;` before the `GRANT` statement it says that there is no table inside the database with the same name as the database. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Check this link http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/control_user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it with

```
GRANT SELECT ON cameracircle.* TO 'hoeym'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you issue a GRANT statement, check that the

> derby.database.sqlAuthorization

property is set to true. The derby.database.sqlAuthorization property enables the SQL Authorization mode.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin lets you do this graphically. From the Users tab, look for Add User then don't select anything for the Global Privileges area. Go ahead and create the user, then edit the privileges. Halfway down the page there's a area for "Database-specific privileges" where you can specify the permissions on a database (or even table-) level.

Comment: Not helpful. I was looking for an SQL answer, seeing as it is an SQL question. Words do not describe how much quicker it is just to write a bunch of sql then copy and paste it all.

Comment: You didn't specify that, and you tagged your post as phpMyAdmin. phpMyAdmin is a tool for graphically working with databases, so since you tagged it as such I gave the answer you seemed to be asking. Please be more specific in the future.

Comment: When I say my code isnt working what did I do wrong I think that is specific enough. As you can see the question says 'What have i done wrong?'